# GLIBC_2.32 not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc

I've been trying to get one of my python programs to run, however, every time I attempt to execute the file through terminal, I get the following error.

```
[12432] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIqEgpsa/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIqEgpsa/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

After doing a few searches on Google, I found that I am one version behind with regards to my Glibc. I ran ldd --version in terminal and I am using Glibc version 2.31. I tried to update my system using 'sudo apt-get update' to no avail.

I'm not really sure what to do right now, and it's very important that I resolve this quickly.

Thank you for reading, and I look forwards to reading the responses.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: From your statement that you have `GLIBC_2.31` currently available, it seems you are using Ubuntu 20.04.  To get `GLIBC_2.32` you would need to use Ubuntu 20.10 or another operating system that offers that version.  Trying to upgrade `glibc` on your existing system will likely lead to many problems.

Comment: Thank you very much @GracefulRestart My linux version is 20.04, so I assume that's why! I'll be getting an updated distro right now.

Answer (score 1):

I am converting the from comment from @gracefulrestart to an answer and expanding on it a bit:

> From your statement that you have GLIBC_2.31 currently available, it seems you are using Ubuntu 20.04. To get GLIBC_2.32 you would need to use Ubuntu 20.10 or another operating system that offers that version. Trying to upgrade glibc on your existing system will likely lead to many problems.

In my case I had reverted a 20.10 -> 20.04.2 installation of Ubuntu due to some bugs.

When I did so, I copied my $HOME folder. It brought with the `.pyenv` folder and that led to my issue.

```
pyenv uninstall 3.9.0
pyenv install 3.9.0
```

fixed the problem.